# Is it possible to call react-intl api methods without inject each component

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

i'm wondering if there's any way to call API methods without inject each component ?

somthing like providing a function that will call intl.formatMessage for example

```
export function t(id,defaultmessage){
console.log("Called ",id,defaultmessage);
return intl.formatMessage(
{
  id: id,
  defaultMessage: defaultmessage
 }
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a state management library such as [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). The data would then be passed into each component as a property, instead of having an API call in each component.

Comment: what i mean is how to call react-intl APi methods, which already exists inside react-intl, but the way they call them is by injection props in other component, which i don't like to implement it